# Pymacs Not Starting up on Emacs24

Tags: emacs, emacs24, pymacs

I'm using Emacs 24 and Pymacs doesn't seem to start up.

I installed pymacs from ELPA. When I write `M-x pymacs-eval` and give an arbitary expression, it gives me the following error:

```
pymacs-report-error: Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds
```

And I get the following message in the Pymacs buffer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name main

Process pymacs exited abnormally with code 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear steps to install pymacs with emacs 24?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255940/clear-steps-to-install-pymacs-with-emacs-24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pymacs from ELPA package didn't seem to work.

Downloading and installing it manually from the [github repository](https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs) made it work. The ELPA package of pymacs only had Emacs lisp files on it (.el files) but the repository contained Python files too and I also ran the command of `sudo python setup.py install` inside it's folder.

Comment: Also you may use `el-get`, recipe pymacs.rcp (it is from github too) works https://github.com/dimitri/el-get